# DotNetOpenAuth: No OpenID endpoint found

Tags: single-sign-on, dotnetopenauth

I've read the following manual: http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_dotnet.html

Am I correct that nothing special is required to be done to use google API for user SSO?

But when I tried to launch "Hello World" for marketplace application it returned me an error:
Blockquote

Blockquote> No OpenID endpoint found. Blockquote

When

```
IAuthenticationRequest request = relyingParty.CreateRequest(openIdBox.Text);
```

was called. The value of "openIdBox.Text" is my google email.

P.S. My investigation of stackoverflow topics linked to the same error gives nothing.

Please advise!

Any thoughts are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use your Google email as your OpenID. Instead, when using Google, you typically use `http://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` as your OpenID; Google will then guide you to ask for your email address. The relying party may not be able to find out what your email address is (depending on whether you approve releasing this data).

Comment: Thank you, it helps. Does it mean that "" supports SSO from another providers in exactly the same way? Or it supports also another implementation provided by Google? Why is it required to have identifier configurable? Thank you a lot!

Comment: I don't understand your questions: what is ""? What other implementation? As for the last one: there are provider IDs, and user IDs. Many OpenID users will enter their user ID, not a provider ID. So it must be configurable. If you know that all your users will use Google accounts, you can skip letting them enter that fact. See how StackOverflow implements OpenID: there is just a Google logo, no need to enter anything.

Comment: Yes, I saw how StackOverflow did that... My question is another,.. and just looked on the dotnetopenauth web site. It seems like it will work with any SSO provider (any one that supports: OpenID 2.0, .x, OAuth 1.0 and 1.0a) and you can ask users to choose any of existing in the web (yahoo, google, etc). For better usability I should provide OpenId that corresponds to selected provider... Please correct me if I wrong.